# How do you fix a kubernetes node if it refusing connections to a NodePort's port?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Over the last couple days, I've seen networking issues in our kubernetes cluster(GKE), most notably that a node immediately closed connections to a Service's port(`NodePort`).  According to the the [user guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-nodeport), the node port should be available on all nodes

> each Node will proxy that port (the same port number on every Node) into your Service.

The node appears up, and if you run `kubectl get node` it is marked as ready, however it will be actively refusing connections on Service ports.  Is there a way, other than to delete the node and have it get rebuilt to get a node to start accepting traffic on those ports?

Comment: In at least 1.3x. there is a bug in kube-proxy which makes it fail and not restart correctly on GCE. Type kubectl get all --namespace=kube-system to see if your kube proxies are not in ErrImagePull. If so, restart the node and the problem disappears.

Comment: @miah did you check the nat table of the local IPtables of your nodes? `iptables -L -n -v -t nat` should give you more details about the chains where your NodePort is involved and see if it's even routed in the end. Could be that there is no endpoint available for that service. In that case `kubectl get ep` should also be a great help.